# webviewglue native destroy view only when javascript is enabled

Tags: javascript, android

I'm trying to use web view within an app it all works except when i enable javascript 
the code i am using is

```
      mWebView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview1);
      mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
      mWebView.loadUrl("http:/google.co.uk");
```

The doesn't work the web view just disappears

```
          mWebView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview1);
      mWebView.loadUrl("http:/google.co.uk");
```

This loads fine

any advice would be great thanks

Comment: I should work ,check with different device.

Comment: i have it starts to load then disappears

Comment: it turns out it was just a certain page i was trying to load, i don't know why it was doing it